# Applying Custom Angular Filter per Element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Looking at [Mastering Web Development with AngularJS](http://www.packtpub.com/angularjs-web-application-development/book?tag=dp/masteringwebwithangularjs-abr1/0913), I ran this custom filter to trim text, cut out the last 3 characters, and append `...` if the input exceeds the LIMIT.

**app.html**

```
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
       <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="s in strs | customTrim:2">
                <td>{{s}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.strs = ["HEY THERE", "me"];

});

myApp.filter('customTrim', function($filter) {
    var limitToFilter = $filter('limitTo');

    console.log("limitToFilter('ABCDEF', 2)", 
        limitToFilter('ABCDEF', 2));

    return function(input, limit) {
        console.log("input:", input, "input.length", input.length,
         "limit:", limit);
        if(input.length > limit) {
            console.log("returning...");
            console.log(limitToFilter(input, limit-3) + "...");
            return limitToFilter(input, limit-3) + "...";
        }
        return input;
    }
});
```

However, the length of `strs`, rather than the individual `s`, appears to be printing out.

How can I pass each item of the array into my `customFilter`?

**Console**

```
limitToFilter('ABCDEF', 2) A 
input: ["HEY THERE", "me"] input.length 2 limit: 2 
input: ["HEY THERE", "me"] input.length 2 limit: 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the filter on the string, not on the array:

```
<tr ng-repeat="s in strs">
    <td>{{s | customTrim:2}}</td>
</tr>
```